# Creating custom Authentication entry point for form login

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a form login entry point currently defined like so:

```xml
<form-login login-page="/spring/login" 
            login-processing-url="/spring/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/spring/loginfail" 
            default-target-url="/spring/loginsuccess" 
            always-use-default-target="true" />
```

This works just fine but I want to convert it into a custom authentication entry point. I have a class that extends  `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` which gets called when authentication is needed.

My question is: *How do I support POSTing the username/password using this pattern?*

When I remove the form-login block I get a POST not supported error.  I guess since I can no longer define the login-processing-url, where do I post the credentials so that Spring Security can perform the authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured this out.  I misunderstood how this works.  The form-login AuthenticationEntryPoint should be a singular entry point in the application.  The AuthenticationEntryPoints mapped to other patterns should simply re-direct to the URL which is mapped to the entry point containing the form-login entry point IF form-login is required, otherwise we could handle this differently.